# bash script that monitor a disk partition's usage

Tags: bash

df shows

```
-bash-4.1# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3            1918217320 1783986384  36791092  98% /
tmpfs                 16417312         0  16417312   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1               482214    148531    308784  33% /boot
/dev/sdb1            1922858352 1373513440 451669312  76% /disk2
```

I need to bash script a function that returns 1 if an paritions become 100% full.
how can this be done?  what commands can I use to parse out the output of df?

Comment: may be `df |grep 100%`?

Comment: `df | awk '$5=="100%" {print $1}'` it will print the filesystem is in 100%.

Comment: A useful limit can also be used: `df -h | tail -n+2 | awk '$5 >= "90%" {print "warning: " $1 " at " $5}'`  Remember, the percentage and available from `df` does not include the system reserve for non-root users (generally 5%).

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
disks_space() {
    ! df -P | awk '{print $5}' | grep -Fqx '100%'
}
```

In other words, check if any of the lines in the fifth column of the POSIX `df` output contains the exact string "100%".

Comment: awk followed by grep? Surely you jest.

Comment: What I meant to convey, but failed, was that that is usually not necessary: `! df -P|awk '$5=="100%" {exit 1}'` I believe it's also more readable and self-documenting than magic grep options. Save a process and a fork today :-)

Comment: I would normally express this as [`! df --portability | awk '{print $5}' | grep --fixed-strings --line-regexp --quiet '100%'`](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/89703236ce04be301e707b7f2497fdcb5d6fc2ce#.bash_history) for readability, but not every incarnation of `grep` supports long options. Your command is very clear, but often `sed`, `awk` and `perl` commands tend to become line noise very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Probelm with percentage is if its a terrabyte disk 95% of that may still be lots of free gig - refer to the bottom script for actual disk space - the format 100 at the end of the example shows alert when it is below 100MB left on a partition

diskspace.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# set -x
# Shell script to monitor or watch the disk space
# It will send an email to $ADMIN, if the (free available) percentage of space is >= 90%.
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Set admin email so that you can get email.
ADMIN="root"
# set alert level 90% is default
ALERT=90
# Exclude list of unwanted monitoring, if several partions then use "|" to separate the partitions.
# An example: EXCLUDE_LIST="/dev/hdd1|/dev/hdc5"
EXCLUDE_LIST="/auto/ripper"
#
#::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
#
function main_prog() {
while read output;
do
echo $output
  usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1)

  partition=$(echo $output | awk '{print $2}')

  if [ $usep -ge $ALERT ] ; then
    if [ "$partition" == "/var" ]; then
             # echo "Running out of space \"$partition ($usep%)\" on server $(hostname), $(date)"
             echo "Running out of space \"$partition ($usep%)\" on server $(hostname), $(date)" |  mail -s "Alert: Almost out of disk space $usep%" $ADMIN

        # Extra bits  you may wish to do -    
        #for FILE in `find $partition -size +1G -print`
        #do
        #    echo $FILE
        #    DATE=`date  +%Y-%m-%d_%H%M`
        #    filename=`echo ${FILE##*/}`
        #    mkdir /mnt/san/$hostname
        #    echo cp $FILE /mnt/san/$(hostname)/$filename-$DATE
        #    #echo > $FILE
        #done
    fi
  fi
done
}
if [ "$EXCLUDE_LIST" != "" ] ; then
  df -hP |  grep -vE "^[^/]|tmpfs|cdrom|${EXCLUDE_LIST}" | awk '{print $5 " " $6}' | main_prog
else
  df -hP |  grep -vE "^[^/]|tmpfs|cdrom"| awk '{print $5 " " $6}' | main_prog
fi
```

Or you could use this style of check I put in place for nagios (using snmp to connect to a remote host)

snmp_remote_disk_auto

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script takes:
# <host> <community> <megs>

snmpwalk="/usr/bin/snmpwalk"
snmpget="/usr/bin/snmpget"

function usage() { 
echo "$0 localhost public 100"
echo "where localhost is server"
echo "public is snmp pass"
echo "100 is when it reaches below a 100Mb"
echo "-----------------------------------"
echo "define threshold below limit specific for partitions i.e. boot can be 50mb where as /var I guess we want to catch it at around 1 gig so"
echo "$0 localhost public  1024"

}


server=$1;
pass=$2
limit=$3;

errors_found="";
partitions_found="";
lower_limit=10;
graphtext="|"

if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
    usage;
    exit 1;
fi

# takes <size> <used> <allocation>
calc_free() {
    echo "$1 $2 - $3 * 1024 / 1024 / p" | dc
}

    for partitions in $($snmpwalk -v2c -c $pass -Oq $server  hrStorageDescr|grep /|egrep -v "(/mnt|/home|/proc|/sys)"|awk '{print $NF}'); do
        if [[ $partitions =~ /boot ]]; then
            limit=$lower_limit;
        fi
        if result=$($snmpwalk -v2c -c $pass -Oq $server hrStorageDescr | grep "$partitions$"); then
            index=$(echo $result | sed 's/.*hrStorageDescr//' | sed 's/ .*//')
            args=$($snmpget -v2c -c $pass -Oqv $server hrStorageSize$index hrStorageUsed$index hrStorageAllocationUnits$index | while read oid j ; do printf " $oid" ; done)
            free=$(calc_free$args)


            back_count=$(echo $partitions|grep -o "/"|wc -l)
            if [[ $back_count -ge 2 ]]; then
                gpartition=$(echo "/"${partitions##*/})
            else
                gpartition=$partitions;
            fi

            if [ "$free" -gt "$limit" ]
            then

                graphtext=$graphtext$gpartition"="$free"MB;;;0 "
                #graphtext=$graphtext$partitions"="$free"MB;;;0 "
                partitions_found=$partitions_found" $partitions ($free MB)"
            else
                graphtext=$graphtext$gpartition"="$free"MB;;;0 "
                #graphtext=$graphtext$partitions"="$free"MB;;;0 "
                errors_found=$errors_found" $partitions ($free MB)"

            fi

        else
                graphtext=$graphtext$gpartition"="0"MB;;;0 "
                #graphtext=$graphtext$partitions"="0"MB;;;0 "
             errors_found=$errors_found" $paritions does_not_exist_or_snmp_is_not_responding"
        fi
    done

    if [ "$errors_found" == "" ]; then
        echo "OK: $partitions_found$graphtext"
        exit 0
    else
        echo "CRITICAL: $errors_found$graphtext";
        exit 2;
    fi
```

`./snmp_remote_disk_auto localhost public 100`

```
OK:  / (1879 MB) /var (2281 MB) /tmp (947 MB) /boot (175 MB)|/=1879MB;;;0 /var=2281MB;;;0 /tmp=947MB;;;0 /boot=175MB;;;0
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a huge fan of excessive greps and awks as it can really bring errors over time..

I would just get the information for the folders that matter. Below is a sample of using stat which will give you the available BYTES in a folder, then converts it to MB (10**6).  I roughly tested this on my RHEL6.x system.

```
    folder_x_mb=$(($(stat -f --format="%a*%s" /folder_x)/10**6))    
    folder_y_mb=$(($(stat -f --format="%a*%s" /folder_y)/10**6))   
    folder_z_mb=$(($(stat -f --format="%a*%s" /folder_z)/10**6))
```

Comment: The only issue with `stat` is it does not reflect the `5%` reserve unavailable to non-root users.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
df | perl -wne 'if(/(\d+)%\s+(.*)/){print "$2 at $1%\n" if $1>90}'
```

You can change the threshold and instead of printing you can just exit:

```
df | perl -wne 'if(/(\d+)%\s+(.*)/){exit 1 if $1>99}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple script to check if there are already disk that reached their maximum capacity and -- if there were it would return / output 1.

```
#!/bin/sh

CHECK=$(df -Ph | grep '100%' | xargs echo | cut -d' ' -f5)

if [ "$CHECK" == "100%"]
then
    echo 1
else
    echo 0
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `df -Ph | grep -v "Use%" | sed 's/%//g' | awk '$5 > LIMIT {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5"%";}' | column -t'`

It will return all `df -Ph` entries that exceed the `LIMIT`

For example, on my workstation, `df -Ph` returns:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1      92G   32G   56G  37% /
shmfs                  98G  304K   98G   1% /dev/shm
192.168.1.1:/apache_cache  2.7T  851G  1.9T  32% /media/backup
/dev/dm-4              50G   49G  1.1G  98% /lun1
/dev/dm-7              247G  30G  218G  12% /lun2
```

Let's say I want to list the mount points that exceed 20% of capacity.

I use `df -Ph | grep -v "Use%" | sed 's/%//g' | awk '$5 > 20 {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5"%";}' | column -t`, and it returns the following:

```
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1      92G   32G   56G  37% /
192.168.1.1:/apache_cache  2.7T  851G  1.9T  32% /media/backup
/dev/dm-4              50G   49G  1.1G  98% /lun1
```

The `column -t` part is here purely for the output to be readable.